# Как в RxJs выполнить функцию если значение BehaviourSubject true, а если false - то ждать пока не станет true?

Tags: angular, rxjs

у меня есть необходимость создать подписку и выполнить значение внутри только если значение другого BehaviourSubject равно true, а если нет, то не пропускать, а ждать, когда станет true и выполнить функцию ?

На самом деле это нужно при смене токена, так как при первом же запросе, если токен устарел, то нужно сперва обновить его и следующие запросы поставить в ожидание и только когда значение изменится, что токен обновлён - выполнить запросы.

Comment: По идее должен подойти `filter` опрератор

Comment: Я вот тоже подумал,что можно не мудрить с совмещающими операторами,а взять сперва проверить,если параметр true,то выполнить запрос, а если false(то есть идёт запрос на новый токен), то подписаться на тот параметр BehaviorSubject с фильтром пропуска на true и взять take(1) и после этого выполнять сам запрос ,который планировался. Правильно мыслю или мудрю и можно проще ?)))

Comment: @RakzinRoman, вроже похоже на правильный ход мыслей. Можно добавить свой код в вопрос, чтобы было точно понятно, что все правильно)